# How to make a striped button

Tags: vb.net, button, custom-controls

I want to be able to create a custom striped button at runtime.
I can create the button and set the background colour.
The button is a custom control with a number of properties.
This doesnt work, the button doesn't have stripes:

```
    Private Sub EventButton_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If isStripy Then

      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New Drawing2D.HatchBrush(Drawing2D.HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.WhiteSmoke, Me.BackColor), Me.Bounds)

    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions or guidance appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your context, but there is a lot more involved in custom drawing a button than a simple rectangle fill. [Take a look at this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26622/Custom-Button-Control-with-Gradient-Colors-and-Ext) perhaps it will be useful as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you shouldn't use the `Me.Bounds`, but use `e.ClipRectangle` instead. `Bounds` will give you the bound position relative to the parent control.

Then you need do two things in the `Button` `Paint` `event` to finish the task;

1. Draw the `Button` BackColor

   ```
   Dim brush As Drawing2D.HatchBrush = New Drawing2D.HatchBrush(Drawing2D.HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.Brown, btn.BackColor)
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle()) 'Draw the background
   ```
2. Redraw the `String` which you erase by redrawing your `BackColor`

   ```
   Dim stringSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(btn.Text, btn.Font) 'Needed to redraw the text
   Dim textX As Single = (e.ClipRectangle().Width - stringSize.Width) / 2 'Assuming in the centre
   Dim textY As Single = (e.ClipRectangle().Height - stringSize.Height) / 2 'Assuming in the centre
   e.Graphics.DrawString(btn.Text, btn.Font, New SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor), textX, textY) 'Redraw the text
   ```

As an example, this is how your code should look like:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub MyButton1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyButton1.Paint
        Dim btn As MyButton = TryCast(sender, MyButton)
        If btn.IsStripy Then            
            Dim brush As Drawing2D.HatchBrush = New Drawing2D.HatchBrush(Drawing2D.HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.Brown, btn.BackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle()) 'Draw the background
            Dim stringSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(btn.Text, btn.Font) 'Needed to redraw the text
            Dim textX As Single = (e.ClipRectangle().Width - stringSize.Width) / 2 'Assuming in the centre
            Dim textY As Single = (e.ClipRectangle().Height - stringSize.Height) / 2 'Assuming in the centre
            e.Graphics.DrawString(btn.Text, btn.Font, New SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor), textX, textY) 'Redraw the text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button
    Public IsStripy As Boolean = True
End Class
```

And you should get the following result (note that the button is stripped)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's great.  I was using the Paint event in the custom control.  I used your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: @DovesandChicks glad that you find it helpful! ;)